# Enter sudo password for lxc-start in pexpect.spawn process with pexpect.spawn.interact

Tags: python, sudo, pexpect, lxc

I want to start an lxc with `sudo lxc-start -n <lxc-name> --lxcpath=/some/custom/path` in a python script and controll it with `pexpect` (login, install a package, add a user and logout/shutdown the lxc). An example would look like this (I'm pretty close to the solution, just need the right `escape_character` argument for `pexpect.spawn.interact`):

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn("sudo lxc-start --name=debian-wheezy-amd64 --lxcpath=/some/custom/path/")
child.expect("Password:") # the sudo password prompt (might be optional if the script has been invoked with sudo (let's keep in anyway as an exercise))
child.interact("??") # tried "\r" -> never returns, "\r\r" and "\n" -> accepts the sudo password, but doesn't give back the control to the python interpreter (stuck at lxc login)
child.expect("login")
child.sendline("root")
# etc. (tasks mentioned above)
child.expect("[#$][\\s]")
child.sendline("shutdown -h 0")
```

Everythings works well if I enter the password with `getpassword`, store it in a variable and pass it with `child.expect("Password:"); child.sendline(mypassword)`, so the solution above is rather an exercise for better understanding of `pexpect`.

Is there a generic `escape_character` for all OSs/lxcs to enter the sudo password or do they differ (and if they do is there a generic way to determine them independent of the knowledge about the OS (e.g. with a shell variable)?)

Comment: Are you looking for an escape character that can't be in the sudo password that you can use to indicate that interaction is done and the script should continue?

Comment: @ThomasK I want to restrict the interactive mode to the entering of the password and leave it afterwards. If the escape character is considered part of the sudo password (I don't know how sudo handles `\n`, `\r` and `\x1d`) or of input in general (recognized by `pexpect`) isn't important.

Comment: The escape character isn't sent through to the child process, so if you make it something like `\n`, pressing enter will stop interaction mode without submitting the password. You could probably do it by making `\n` the escape character, and then doing `child.sendline()` immediately after interact.